# How can html5test.com detect the exact name of browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, android, html5, user-agent

Whene i open html5test.com using "dolphin browser" on galaxy s6 nougat
the website tell me :
**"You are using Dolphin on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0"**

the user agent string =
`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36`

when i past it on User-Agent Switcher for Chrome (on windows 7)

html5test.com tell me :
**You are using Chromium WebView 58 on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0**

last thing this is quick comparison between google chrome and dolphin browser

**Chrome** `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36`

**Dolphin** `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G920F Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36`

the only difference is  `; wv` and `Version/4.0`

Comment: So, what is the question? You’ve just indicated the user agent strings are different, what behavior do you expect?

Comment: my question how How can html5test.com detect the exact name of browsers and other website as whatismybrowser.com and http://detectmobilebrowsers.com tell me **Chrome 58 on Android (Nougat)** or **You are using Chromium WebView 58 on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0** why they cant detect as **Dolphin**

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at, this information is all encoded into the browser string.

The part you may be glossing over is the "SM-G920F" which is the model number for a Galaxy S6 smartphone.

The Dolphin Browser bit is an educated guess on behalf of the website, which its most likely getting because of a combination of Safari and Android (Safari does not run on Android, and [its a tell-tale sign that someone is most likely using Dolphin](http://ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999106/how-to-detect-dolphin-browser-in-javascript))